# How to sor a dictionary by key?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sort my dictionary by key only but I failed.

My dictionary is

```
myDic={'a':{},'b':{},'c':{}}

sorted(myDic.items(),reverse=True)
```

but it returns

```
{'a': {}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}
```

but I want `{'c': {}, 'b': {}, 'a': {}}`
sort by descending order

Comment: It works for me when I run it. I think you're doing something wrong, as sorted returns a list, and in your case it's a dictionary

Comment: thank you I check my python version , it was 2.7

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` will always return a list. You can’t have sorted dictionaries as before Python 3.6, dictionaries have no order.

You seem to have forgotten to assign your value to a variable:

```
myDic = {{'a':{},'b':{},'c':{}}
sorted_keys = sorted(myDic, reverse=True)
```

I didn’t sort `myDic.items()` as we only need to sort the keys into a list.

Now when you want to loop over the dictionary ‘in order’, iterate over the list of sorted keys and get the corresponding value from the dictionary:

```
for key in sorted_keys:
    print(myDic[key])
```